# What to look for in a company's annual report?

Tags: investing, terminology, annual-report

For a beginner in stock investing, looking at a company's annual report can be an overwhelming experience. You can typically expect to see 50-100 pages of accounting lingo that may sound natural to someone trained, but seems so overly complicated without proper training.

However, I did read a few reports and generally know that most of the critical numbers are being condensed into a few large tables, many times called statement of profit & loss, s. of income, financial position, changes in equity, cash flows.

How do you know, without learning all the lingo, where a red or green flag is 'hidden' in these tables, so then you can make an informed decision of whether the company is or is not worth investing in.

Thanks

Comment: I think this quote from the [help section](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) is applicable here: "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."

Comment: Read university-level accounting textbooks, and forensic accounting textbooks to learn about shady accounting practices. Then read valuation textbooks. At the same time, practice by reading annual reports. After all this, you should know what to look for. For a beginner, I would expect this to take at least a year of persistent study.

Comment: Short answer: Start reading textbooks that teach you what to look for.